# How can I run an ExecStartPost command from a systemd unit file that may or may not terminate

Tags: systemd

I am trying to write a systemd unit file. When I start the service siad, I then want to launch another command, /usr/sbin/clearshare-scheduler.sh, which may run for hours or it may complete immediately. I've tried doing this with an ExecStartPost but systemd does not like it if the command does not complete in a short time and gives failure message.
A sample file is:

```
[Unit]
Description=Siad
After=syslog.target network.target

[Service]
Type=simple
OOMScoreAdjust=500
PIDFile=/var/run/siad.pid
EnvironmentFile=/etc/sysconfig/siad
Environment="SIA_DATA_DIR=/var/lib/siad-data"
ExecStart=/usr/bin/siad $EXTRA_ARGS
ExecStop=/usr/bin/siac stop
WorkingDirectory=/var/lib/sia/
ExecStartPost=/usr/bin/sh -c 'umask 022; /usr/bin/pgrep siad > /var/run/siad.pid'
ExecStartPost=/usr/sbin/clearshare-scheduler.sh

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

I have tried launching it with an "&" to put it into the background and with a nohup but they do not work either.

Answer (score 0):

Test to add `TimeoutStartSec=` under `[Service]`. It affect all the start up procedure.

https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.service.html#TimeoutStartSec=

Comment: Would that help? As far as I can see, /usr/sbin/clearshare-scheduler.sh can run for days or exit immediately. I want the service to start ans say that it is running irrespective of the running state of clearshare-scheduler.sh. Also, if it is relevant, clearshare-scheduler.sh does not daemonise. It is like I want to run clearshare-scheduler.sh not under the control of systemd, but launched within systemd.

Comment: Did u consider to have a second systemd service (Oneshot maybe ? ) dependent from this first service ?

Comment: I had but how do you make the second service start when the first service starts? Also, if the second service (clearshare-scheduler.sh) starts and terminates immediately, which it will do once it has run successfully once, will its status then show as failed?

Comment: Can I add a BindsTo in the first service when the second is a Type=OneShot? Would that work?

Comment: No. It looks like a BindsTo in the first service won't work as when the second one stops/exits, the first will then be killed. Would PartOf= work in the second service?

Answer (score 0):

Simply add the command `/usr/sbin/clearshare-scheduler.sh` as the second service requires your first service. I hope this helps!